# Facing a problem in Converting integer (from 0 to 999) to English word only by using if-else in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newbie at python programming at trying to convert a given integer variable (from 0 to 999) to English words. In case of providing an input number > 99 i.e. 136 it's showing an error =>

"IndexError: list index out of range"

Code is:

```
words_upto_19 = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three','four', 'five', 'six','seven', 'eight','nine','ten','eleven','twelve','therteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen']
words_for_tens = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','fourty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']
words_for_hundred = ['','one hundred','two hundred', 'three hundred','four hundred', 'five hundred', 'six hundred','seven hundred', 'eight hundred','nine hundred']

n = int(input("Enter a number between 0 to 999:"))

output = ''

if n == 0:
    output = 'zero'
elif n<= 19:
    output = words_upto_19[n]
elif n<= 99:
    output = words_for_tens[n//10]+' '+ words_upto_19[n%10]
elif n<=999:
    output = words_for_hundred[n//100]+' '+ words_for_tens[n//10]+' '+ words_upto_19[n%10]
else:
    output = 'Entered value is more than 999!'
print(output)
```

The problem is showing at the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\py codes\Untitled-1.py", line 16, in <module>
    output =  words_for_tens[n//10]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What should I do??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `136//10` is 13, which is more than the number of elements in your list.

Comment: then what should I do?